# Any option to exclude some files from delete in windows using ansible

Tags: windows, ansible

I want to exclude some files from deleting in windows using `win_file` module.
Unfortunately `exclude` option is there only for Linux module `file`, I believe.

1. I am getting updated application code from developer. I need to keep some files without any change in the windows application  like "web.config". In that case I only need to exclude one or two files and I can replace all other files.

Other option I have is, I need to copy original "web.config" in my src folder and idempotent will work.

Comment: Based on what should those files be "excluded"?

Comment: Also, there is no exclude option in `file` module that I can see either: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html

Comment: I am updating my application code,updated code my developer will keep in s3 bucket. So I need to replace all the files in application document root except "web.config"

Comment: The proper way of handling this would be to actually create the web.config. Ansible is built for configuration management so it should be managing that file instead of actively avoiding it. Ideally, your deployment workflow should look somewhat like this: clean src folder -> download code from s3 -> create web.conf ( and other configuration ) -> restart services.